# Is there a special tool to remove this shower cartridge cover?

Tags: shower, tools, bathroom-fixtures

Underneath the shower handle I've found this interesting design where there's a cover or shroud encapsulating the cartridge. The threading on it is interesting: the threading isn't required for the handle and there are two flat areas near the end. I'm guessing there's a special tool I should use to get access to the cartridge. (No, I don't think I'm referring to a cartridge puller.)

How would I find this tool? Or can anybody identify the manufacturer?

[image: Disassembled mystery shower mixer cover]
[image: Assembled mystery shower mixer showing handle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear to be any "special" tool requirement per these pictures.

Put a strap wrench on the outermost silver bit and unscrew, or (judging the beat-up look it already has) just scar it up some more with slip joint pliers like the last guy did, at a guess. If the central part turns when you do that, put a wrench on the flats to prevent it from turning as you unscrew the silver part. If the silver bits are more conjoined than it appears, you might need to take the screw(s) in the wall out too.